# How do I forward a Twilio number to a VoIP phone?

Tags: twilio, voip, twilio-twiml

Twilio noob + VoIP noob here, so brace yourself for a double-dumb question.

I have a local Twilio number that currently points to a text-to-speech voicemail greeting. I get a lot of hang-ups (empty voicemail messages), so I would prefer to start routing my incoming calls to a VoIP phone during business hours.

I only have one question about this so far: **HOW?**

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Forwarding voice calls from a Twilio number to a VoIP client.
Example with Zoiper VoIP client (https://www.zoiper.com/).

### Twilio configuration

#### *Step 1 - Configure credentials*

Log on to your Twilio console (Master Account or switch to a Subaccount), then go to: **Programmable Voice >> SIP Domains >> Credential Lists** https://www.twilio.com/console/voice/sip/cls

[image]

Click on "**Create new Credential List**"

[image]

Remember the username and password, you will need it for Zoiper VoIP client configuration.

#### ***Step 2 - Configure SIP domain***

Once you've created a credential list, go to **Voice SIP Domains** https://www.twilio.com/console/voice/sip/endpoints

Click on "**Create new SIP Domain**"

Enter values for:

**FRIENDLY NAME**: "My SIP Domain"

**SIP URI**: "something" (the '*something*' has to be some unique name) you will need this `something` when you configure Zoiper.

[image]

then for **CREDENTIAL LISTS** select "My List" (the one you created on 'Credential Lists'.

[image]

also for **SIP Registration** section, down the page, select **ENABLED** and again for **CREDENTIAL LISTS** select "My List"

[image]

Don't forget to "**Save**"

#### ***Step 3 - Configure a TwiML Bin***

Next, you need to **create a TwiML Bin**, go to https://www.twilio.com/console/runtime/twiml-bins and let's call it "**SipBin**" with the folowing code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
<Dial>
  <Sip>
    alex@something.sip.us1.twilio.com  
  </Sip>
</Dial>
</Response>
```

Note the `alex@something` part is `alex` from when we created the credential list and `something` from when we created the SIP domain.

Save this bin.

#### ***Step 4 - Configure Twilio phone number***

Next configure the Twilio phone number, as when a voice call comes in to run the TwiML from the bin. https://www.twilio.com/console/phone-numbers/incoming

[image]

**Save** the phone number configuration. Next, let's configure Zoiper.

---

### Zoiper configuration

Download and install the Zoiper VoIP client app on your smartphone (https://www.zoiper.com/).

Launch the app, click on the "hamburger" menu at top left then go to `Settings` then to `Accounts`.

Select the "**SIP**" tab, then click on the "**+**" (plus) sign to add an account. It will ask you for a "**Username/Login**" and a "**Password**".

Enter the ones you used when you created the credential list at Twilio.

Click the "**Login**" button, it will take you to next page to enter "**hostname or provider**".

Enter `something.sip.us1.twilio.com`, replace `something` with your name choice when you configured the **SIP URI** at Twilio.

Click "**Next**", it will take you to a page regarding "provider/PBX authentication or outbound proxy".

Do not check the box, click "**Skip**".

On the next page, wait until Zoiper connects to Twilio, it will automatically find "**SIP TLS**" , it will go green.

You can now click "**Finish**".

You're done, call your Twilio number and Zoiper will ring.

---

### Update: **Outgoing Calls Configuration** (only needed at Twilio)

***Step 1***

To make outgoing calls work you will need to create a second Twilio Bin, let's call it ***SipBinOut*** with the folowing code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
  <Dial callerId="+13335557777">{{#e164}}{{To}}{{/e164}}</Dial>
</Response>
```

replace `+13335557777` with your Twilio number.

After you save the bin, retain (copy) the bin's URL from the *Properties* section at the top (see picture below).

---

[image]

---

***Step 2***

Go to the `Sip Domain Configuration` page for your SIP Domain (the one where you entered the FRIENDLY NAME and the SIP URI).

In the section for `Voice Configuration` configure the `REQUEST URL`, paste the `SipBinOut` URL from the previous step (keep the method `HTTP POST`).

Save with the button at the bottom.

Comment: Wow, thanks for this amazingly detailed response! I'll try this during the week and let you know how it goes.

Comment: Is there a version of this that routes the number to a dedicated VOIP handset rather than an app on a personal phone? This would be used by multiple people at a store's front desk, so a personal device won't work. Thanks again!

Comment: Configuring your VoIP phone would be similar, it should be mentioned in phone's documentation/manual or search Internet for your specific model.

Comment: Thank you very much! Incoming calls worked. Tell me pls how to make outgoing calls work?

Comment: @AlexBaban You are awesome! If you do not mind, I'll try to ask one more question: do you have such an instruction for SMS?

Comment: @AlexBaban, Could you please just explain outgoing call method.As you mentioned in step 1 of outgoing call setup, there is no URL at the top of Properties section.I am adding somthing like this from Herokku  [link](http://mytwiliotest.herokuapp.com/voice?callerId=+18xxxxxxxxx)

Comment: @AlexBaban I've asked the equivalent question for SMS: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52100722/sms-messaging-using-twilio-with-sip

Comment: @Rajendra I've updated the answer with a picture, you can see the `URL` section under `Properties` for the bin.

Comment: @brandones , Sorry, but I don't know if Twilio supports SMS over SIP, hopefully somebody can clarify on your question.