# Twilio Client (Skype Like) Without Building One - Where Can I Find It?

Tags: twilio

Twilio is cool and has great prices for calls and toll-free. I have used it with Zoho CRM, but I would like to use it without being tied to a CRM.

Is there some service or place where you can just download or use ready-made web or windows clients? I want to use Twilio similar to how I would use Skype - and have it automatically / easily connect to my Twilio account. My Google searches have not returned any results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest (already built client) I can think of is a SIP client, something like Zoiper.

Take a look at my answer in the link (it only describes the setup for voice but you could add messaging too):

[How do I forward a Twilio number to a VoIP phone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48346740/how-do-i-forward-a-twilio-number-to-a-voip-phone/48352208#48352208)

Comment: Also, with [Twilio SIP Registration](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/voice/sip-registration) you can use any SIP client with a Twilio number. I've used [Linphone on iOS](https://itunes.apple.com/au/app/linphone/id360065638?mt=8) successfully with a Twilio number before.