# Are there are any off-the-shelf solutions for making outbound calls with Twilio's phone numbers via browser or app?

Tags: twilio

Eg. some service where you just authorize your twilio account or hook up your API details and you're ready to go.

Thanks!

Comment: Zoiper is such an app and I have an answer how to configure here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48346740/how-do-i-forward-a-twilio-number-to-a-voip-phone/48352208#48352208), I hope it helps.

Comment: Awesome write-up, thanks!