# SMS messaging using Twilio with SIP

Tags: twilio, sip, twilio-twiml

I'm trying to use Twilio to send and receive SMS on my iPhone. I've gotten inbound and outbound calling set up [following these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48346740/how-do-i-forward-a-twilio-number-to-a-voip-phone). I'd like the equivalent instructions for SMS. I'm presently using [Zoiper](https://www.zoiper.com/) as a SIP client, but that's flexible.

The phone number configuration page (from [here](https://www.twilio.com/console/phone-numbers/) click a phone number) has a section called "Messaging" which allows one to configure a TwiML bin. However, I haven't been able to find any documentation about how to configure SMS over SIP, let alone TwiML code.

Comment: I don't believe you send SMS over SIP. SMS uses a protocol called SMPP. I couldn't see anywhere in the Zoiper documentation that mentioned SMS messages either.

Comment: Zoiper does have a "Chat" section. The two kinds of accounts it seems to support, though, are SIP and IAX. Presumably at least one of these supports messaging.

Comment: When I try to send messages via Zoiper (with a SIP account registered and successfully making/receiving calls via Twilio), I see a little red X icon, and the details say `Error: Request Timeout (408)`. I can't find anything in [Twilio's SMS TwiML docs](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/twiml/message) about sending an SMS to SIP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Twilio doesn't support SMS or Video over SIP, only Voice.** Sorry about that! let me know if you have any other question related to this.

Comment: Any reference to official Twilio documentation? As this stands, it just sounds like you're speaking on behalf of Twilio.

Comment: I would like to correct you that I am not linked to Twilio in any way. I have been working on Twilio services for quite some time and the answer was based on my experience as I have already tried this previously. @Phil nash is Twilio Evangelist, he can also confirm the same.

Comment: If you need to confirm it by the Twilio team. Submit a ticket here: https://www.twilio.com/console/support/tickets/create