# How to redirect incoming call to SIP ip address with twiml?

Tags: twilio, sip, twilio-twiml

I'm using Twilio (twiml code) for incoming calls. I need to redirect incoming call to remote SIP ip address. How can I do it ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a TwiML similar to this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
<Dial>
  <Sip>
    alex@something.sip.us1.twilio.com  
  </Sip>
</Dial>
</Response>
```

Note: there is more configuration needed, see the answer to  [How do I forward a Twilio number to a VoIP phone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48346740/how-do-i-forward-a-twilio-number-to-a-voip-phone/48352208#48352208)

Also, this blog post has more information https://www.twilio.com/blog/registering-sip-phone-twilio-inbound-outbound