# How to call via SIP client using Twilio?

Tags: twilio, sip

My company wants to use Twilio. I need:
1. Buy an Indonesian number (no problem)
2. Add internal numbers for 3 managers
3. Configure SIP clients (iOS \ Android - Zoiper) so that our managers can call their clients

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48346740/how-do-i-forward-a-twilio-number-to-a-voip-phone/48352208#48352208

Answer (score 0):

Here is a step-by-step blog that will help you with Step #3.

[Registering a SIP Phone Directly to Twilio (and so much more...)](https://www.twilio.com/blog/registering-sip-phone-twilio-inbound-outbound)