# Can't seem to figure out how to perform an incoming call using Twilio?

Tags: node.js, twilio, twilio-programmable-voice

So, I'm new to Twilio and have been trying to build a full VoIP app. I can make outbound calls, but I'm not sure how to get an incoming call to be answered with Twilio and talking to a real person. I've scrolled through what seems like most of their documentation and can't seem to figure this out, and there doesn't seem to be any tutorials out there to help either.

I have the basic incoming function that is provided:

```
function incoming() {
  const voiceResponse = new VoiceResponse();
  voiceResponse.say("Congratulations! You have received your first inbound call! Good bye.");
  console.log('Response:' + voiceResponse.toString());
  return voiceResponse.toString();
}
```

I know how to do call forwarding, but for this VoIP application that isn't really what I want. I am using the Twilio trial account still. I am trying to set this VoIP app up on iOS if that makes a difference.

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: what do you mean by "incoming call to be answered with Twilio and talking to a real person" ?

Comment: So like say if someone calls me with their cellphone on my twilio number I want to be able to talk to them with my twilio number without having to forward the call to a cell number. I'm not really sure if there's a technical term for it

Comment: I believe you're trying to build something like Zoiper (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48346740/how-do-i-forward-a-twilio-number-to-a-voip-phone/48352208#48352208)

Comment: Yes! That's perfect, thank you so much!!

Now, at the risk of sounding dumb, but I just need a little more clarification, I thought Twilio was a VoIP provider? Or is it a VoIP provider like WhatsApp and can only really have a call with Twilio numbers?

Again, thank you so much for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: (https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/voip-sdk/ios/get-started) and (https://www.twilio.com/voice/sip-registration) and maybe (https://www.twilio.com/docs/sip-trunking)